# Haskell, reading another process's memory

Tags: windows, haskell, winapi, memory

I am trying to read the value of the base address of another process and output it.

I am getting the handle like so:
`handle <- openProcess 0x0010 False PID`

then trying to read the base address like so `result <- peekP handle BASE_ADDRESS`

However this obviously errors as it doesn't know what type it should be reading so I get:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `peekP' prevents the constraint `(Storable a0)' from being solved.`
```

I believe I should use `::` somehow to specify the type of the storable I want to use but couldn't find anywhere that explained how to do this.

It would be great if someone could show me how to do this.

Sorry if this is a stupid question any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @typetetris I tried the first suggestion and got `Couldn't match expected type 'IO a0' with actual type 'Int32'`, looking at the source they all use readProcessMemory I just thought peekP copied it to a separate buffer so wanted to use that one.

Comment: @typetetris According to the so rule, please organize an answer instead of comment, in order to make it easier for people with the same issue find out.

Comment: Did so, deleted my comments, which went into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [peekP Documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.8.4.0/docs/System-Win32-DebugApi.html#v:peekP) the signature of `peekP` is

```
peekP :: Storable a => PHANDLE -> ForeignAddress -> IO a
```

so it's polymorphic in the return type.

If the compiler isn't able to deduce the concrete type used instead the type variable `a` it will issue such (or similar) an error message as you see it.

As you suggested, you can help the compiler along with a type annotation, for example

```
result <- ((peekP handle BASE_ADDRESS) :: IO Int32)
```

There is also [peekProcessMemory](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.8.4.0/docs/System-Win32-DebugApi.html#v:peekProcessMemory) which I guess by its name would be more appropriate.